# how to display different colors on each column of a row using ngClass in agular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have 4 rows, each row contains 3 cards.
I am fetching information for these cards from db then rendering them using ngfor in html.
The problem is I want each of card of a row to show different color.

Example:->

ROW 1:
BLUECARD | WHITECARD | REDCARD

ROW 2:
BLUECARD | WHITECARD | REDCARD

as of now I able to do for two colors but how can I make it for 3 colors as I stated in example.

```
<div *ngFor="let r of rates; let i=index;"> 
  <div class="box" [ngClass]="i % 2 == 0 ? 'BLUECARD' : 'REDCARD'">
   <!-- card contents -->
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am able to show 2 colors alternatively but how can I show 3 colors instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an string array with your colors and then `[ngClass]=colorArray[i]` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these (meanwhile i am using silly logic for example only) :-

```
[ngClass]="{1 : 'BLUECARD', 2 : 'REDCARD', 3 : 'WHITECARD'}[i % 2]"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="{'BLUECARD': i % 2 === 0, 'REDCARD' : i % 2 !== 0, 'WHITECARD': i % 2 === undefined }"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this
I created a function that returns a color based on what you give it as a parameter;
In your case, you can create a function that takes i as parameter and returns a color

```
<div class="box" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':giveCouleur(i)}">
   <!-- card contents -->
</div>
```

In your ts file

```
giveCouleur(i:any){
    
    var color="default_color";//or null if you want
    if(i%2==0){
      color="Your_colr";
      //ex:color="#ffffff"

    }else if(i%3==0){
      color="your_color";    
    }else{
      color="your_color" 
    }
    //In this case, you can create as many conditions as you want.
    return color;
  }
```

you can try with ngClass

```
<div class="box" [ngClass]="{giveCouleur(i)}">
       <!-- card contents -->
</div>

giveCouleur(i:any){
    var color="default_color";//or null if you want
    if(i%2==0){
      color="BLUECARD";

    }else if(i%3==0){
      color="REDCARD";    
    }else{
      color="WHITECARD" 
    }
    //In this case, you can create as many conditions as you want.
    return color;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but these are static. Rows may increase in future then it'll not work like this

Comment: you can also apply the function to ngClass see, I just modified the answer

Comment: No, I mean you hardcoded ```if i ==5``` that will work for now but later rows will be hundreds then this condition will not work

Comment: it was just an example, you can put the condition you want

Comment: That's the problem somehow I am not able to build such logic for dynamic values.

Comment: ok, thanks
you can test the other answers